# load picture directx 12 oculus rift

Tags: c, visual-studio, directx

I am implementing an image viewer for oculus rift with DirectX 12, but I am not able to load an image from a file in visual studio. Can someone tell me how to upload an image in DirectX 12?

Answer (score 1):

The DirectX 12 official samples can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples). See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568302/what-is-the-d3d12-equivalent-of-d3d11-createtexture2d) for a code snippet of creating and uploading a texture.

You can also make use of the `DDSTextureLoader` and `WICTextureLoader` modules in the [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started). Note it is a C++ library and that pure C coding for DirectX is not a well-supported scenario.

See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2016/09/15/getting-started-with-direct3d-12/) for more resources.

> If you are new to DirectX, I strongly advice you start with DirectX 11. DirectX 12 is an expert API that builds upon a foundation of all the concepts and techniques of DirectX 11 including HLSL programmable shaders. See [DirectX Tool Kit for DX11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).